# How to Consume an API & Display Results in a List

Tags: reactjs, api, state

I'm creating a trivia game using ReactJS, and the following API endpoint: https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&difficulty=medium&type=boolean

From my understanding, I want to consume the API in `ComponentDidMount()` lifecycle method. From there I'm trying to `map()` over each item in this response (there should be 5 questions in total), and save them to an empty questions array (which is part of my component's state). Finally, I want to display these questions in a list.

I've tried all sorts of angles including `async await`, `fetch()` & `.then()`, `using axios.get`, etc. Here's an example of what I've been trying most recently. I'm just not sure how to consume the API, save those questions to the empty questions array to state, and then iterate over, and render the questions in the DOM.

Please note: I have tried `console.log(this.state.questions)`, which shows the response as code 200, and my original API endpoint URL, but no questions data. I don't understand where the questions are at this point! Please help!

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      questions: [],
      score: 0,
      current: 0,
      loading: false
    }
  }

async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      this.setState({ loading: true })
      this.setState({ questions: await fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&difficulty=medium&type=boolean'), loading: false })
      console.log("state", this.state.questions);
      console.log("props", this.props.questions);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log("component just updated!");
  }

// another ComponentDidMount Attempt
// async componentDidMount(){
//     try {
//       this.setState({loading:true})
//       this.setState({questions: await fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&difficulty=medium&type=boolean'), loading: false})
//         .then(questions => questions.json())
//         .then(questions => this.setState({questions, loading:false}))
//         console.log("state", this.state.questions);
//         console.log("props", this.props.questions);
//       } catch(err) {
//         console.log(err)
//       }
//
//   }

// attempt with axios ()
    // componentDidMount() {
    // axios
    //   .get("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&difficulty=medium&type=boolean")
    //   .then(response => {
    //     this.setState({ question: response.data.question });
    //     this.setState({ category: response.data.category });
    //     // this.setState({ type: response.data.type });
    //     // this.setState({ url: response.data.url });
    //     // this.setState({ score: response.data.score });
    //     console.log("axios GET worked");
    //   })
    //   .catch(err => {
    //     console.log(
    //       "Oops, something broke with GET in componentDidMount() - we've got a: ",
    //       err.message
    //     );
    //   });
    // }

// below is having an issue with .map() - maybe bc questions
// is object containing arrays(?)
  //
  // render() {
  //   return (
  //     <div>
  //       {this.state.loading
  //         ? "loading..."
  //         :  <div>
  //           {
  //             this.state.questions.map(question => {
  //             return(
  //             <div>
  //               <h3>Category: {question.category}</h3>
  //               <h4>Question: {question.question}</h4>
  //             </div>
  //             )
  //           })
  //         }
  //         </div>
  //       }
  //
  //       <HomeCard />
  //       <QuizCard />
  //       <ResCard />
  //     </div>
  //   );
  // }

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```js
async componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    loading: true
  });
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&difficulty=medium&type=boolean');
    const data = await response.json();

    this.setState({
      questions: data.results,
      loading: false
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-bogdan-g5mub

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because the call to **setState is asynchronous** too and because of that your `console.log(this.state.question);` is executed before of the state update. In order to fix the problem, you can pass a callback as the second argument to setState, **this callback will be executed after the state update.**

It should look like this:

```
this.setState(
   { 
       questions: await fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php amount=5&difficulty=medium&type=boolean'), 
       loading: false 
   },
   () => {
       console.log("questions", this.state.questions);
       console.log("loading", this.state.loading);
   }
)
```

You can find more info about here: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value.

I hope that this helps you.

Comment: Your explanation helped me understand the errors in my code, in the context of state & async!! Thank you Donato!